# What's the intuition for the reflection of a quantum particle at a potential step equal to the particle's energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, reflection, scattering

While doing the problem of potential step, I saw that if the energy of the particle is equal to the potential energy of the step, then the wave function is a constant, or to say the probability current in the region 2 is zero ($T=0$). Does that mean that particle is reflected completely ($R=1$)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if $E=V_0$,  then $R=1$ ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schrödinger_equation_for_a_step_potential#Transmission_and_reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_for_a_step_potential#Transmission_and_reflection)) as the wave vector in the high potential region $k_2=0$ ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schrödinger_equation_for_a_step_potential#Solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_for_a_step_potential#Solution)), and this does not look counter-intuitive as $R=0$ for all $E<V_0$.